# assembly randomrange always same output

Tags: assembly, random, x86, masm, irvine32

The Irvine  procedure gives always the same output.

What would be a better way to get random numbers each time the program executed?

```
TITLE Program Template    (Template.asm)


INCLUDE Irvine32.inc


.data


.code
main PROC


mov eax, 6
call RandomRange 
call writeint


    exit    
main ENDP



END main
```

Comment: What's `RandomRange`?  Does it require a seed?

Comment: It is a function in x86 assembly language at Irvine lab. The only use of it I know is the one I already typed in question. With seed I am not sure what you mean I am new to programming.

Comment: We can see it's assembly language.  That doesn't tell us anything about what `RandomRange` is, how it's implemented, how it works, or what it's supposed to do - though from the name I guess we can glean something.  What's in `Irvine32.inc`, for example?  Where does this `RandomRange` function come from, and what does the documentation say about it?

Comment: In question I asked a better way to get random numbers. As I wanted to say it generates random numbers by the algorithm;
; Returns an unsigned pseudo-random 32-bit integer
; in EAX, between 0 and n-1. Input parameter:
; EAX = n.

I did not know that I need to explain all the procedures and terms I asked in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have learned that I needed to use randomize function before using randomrange function. The code should be like:

```
.
.
call randomize
mov eax, 6
call RandomRange 
call writeint
.
.
```

for example.

Thank you all who read the question.